# pyplot: remove vertical black lines between subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I'm trying to create a multiplot of several ECG recordings. For some reason, it's leaving these vertical black lines between the columns. I work with healthcare data, so I'm running this in jupyterlab on a secure server. The lines only appear when graphing on that server, not when I try to recreate the plots with simulated data locally. The version of matplotlib is the same on the server and locally (3.4.3).

Below is the code (including creating simulated data), and I will attach [a censored version of what i'm getting][1] with the patient data on the server.

```
import neurokit2 as nk, pandas as pd, numpy as np,random,matplotlib.pyplot as plt,matplotlib.ticker as ticker

ls_leads = ['I','aVR','V1','V4','II','aVL','V2','V5','III','aVF','V3','V6']

ls_dfs = [] 

for i in ls_leads:
    lead = pd.DataFrame({'{}'.format(i):nk.signal_simulate(duration=2.5, sampling_rate=500,frequency=[random.uniform(0.4,5),random.uniform(0.4,5),random.uniform(0.4,5)],amplitude = [random.uniform(0,1),random.uniform(0,1),random.uniform(0,1)])})
    ls_dfs.append(lead)
df = pd.concat(ls_dfs, axis=1)
df = df.T

x = [i for i in range(1250)]

def plot_individual(ax, x, y,label):
    ax.plot(x, y, color='black', linewidth=0.5)
    ax.minorticks_on()
    ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(200))
    ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(10))   
    ax.annotate(label, xy=(0.02, 0.50), xycoords='axes fraction', fontsize=12, ha='left', va='bottom', fontfamily='serif')
    ax.grid(which='major', linestyle='-', linewidth='0.5', color='red')
    ax.grid(which='minor', linestyle='-', linewidth='0.5', color=(1, 0.7, 0.7))
    ax.tick_params(left=False, bottom=False, labelleft=False, labelbottom=False)
    ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)  # Hide the top spine
    ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)  # Hide the right spine
    ax.spines['bottom'].set_visible(False)  # Hide the bottom spine
    ax.spines['left'].set_visible(False)  # Hide the left spine
    ax.set_facecolor('white')

fig, axs = plt.subplots(3,4, figsize=(16,9),sharex=True,sharey=True, gridspec_kw={'wspace': 0,'hspace':0})  # Adjust figsize as desired
plt.subplots_adjust(
        hspace = 0, 
        wspace = 0.04,
        left   = 0.04,  # the left side of the subplots of the figure
        right  = 0.98,  # the right side of the subplots of the figure
        bottom = 0.06,  # the bottom of the subplots of the figure
        top    = 0.95)
num_columns = 1250

for i, (idx, row) in enumerate(df.iterrows()):
    x_vals = [i for i in range(1250)]
    y_vals = row.to_list()
    plotvals = pd.DataFrame({'x':x_vals,'y':y_vals})
    x = plotvals['x']
    y=plotvals['y']
    ax = axs[i // 4, i % 4] 
    plot_individual(ax, x, y,label=idx)

#plt.tight_layout()  # Adjust the spacing between subplots
plt.show()
```

The following had no effect

- `wspace/hspace = 0` both within `plt.subplots` and `plt.subplots_adjust` functions
- changing values for left/right in `plt.subplots_adjust`
- making background white for individual plots (`ax.set_facecolor('white')`)
- hiding spines for individual plots e.g. `ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)`

Any help is appreciated - thanks!
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AEzXf.png

Comment: Unrelated question: Is sharing anonymous ECG recordings a HIPAA violation?

Comment: I am not able to reproduce the lines with the given code (I am running Maptlotlib 3.7.0). I recommend cutting out as much as you can while still showing the error. For example, get rid of the grid if it doesn't affect the lines. Also get rid of the data, the tick locator, etc. Remove them one-by-one until you have the bare minimum to produce the issue.